# Error: $injector:unpr AngularJS Testing mocking object instances

Tags: angularjs, testing, mocha.js

I keep running into problems at the minute when i'm testing my AngularJS applications, I try and inject all dependencies however it doesn't seem to be working, any help is greatly appreciated :)

It's quite a large application and i'm trying to break things down as much as possible and test them, however we have a factory called `firebaseUser` which is, as you can guess a firebaseUser. We also have an instance of this known as `userInstance` so I'm getting errors whenever I try and mock userInstance.

```
describe('Dashboard Start Controller', function () {

  var scope, ctrl;

  beforeEach(function () {
    MockFirebase.override();
    module('noodleApp.start');
    module('noodleApp.noodleFactory');
    module('noodleApp.firebaseUser');
    module('noodleApp.start');
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $injector) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('StartController', {$scope: scope});
  }));

  afterEach(function () {
    scope.$destroy();
  });

  it('should be available', function() {
    expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should init with filter being set to all', function() {
    expect(scope.filterOn).toBe('all');
  });
});
```

Whenever I run this test I get the following error: `Unknown provider: userInstanceProvider <- userInstance <- StartController`

Comment: In your code sample, there is no "userInstance". So it seems to get loaded in another file. Does your test have access to the file containing the userInstance factory? Are all files loaded? Do you perhaps need something like module('noodleApp.userInstance'); Or perhaps something like scope.userInstance = xyz? Just a guess... :)

Comment: Have you included the module name for the userInstance factory as a dependency of StartController or one of the other modules listed in the first `beforeEach()`? The error indicates that it's missing from all of those (it must be referenced in at least one of them).

Comment: The userInstance isn't a factory, it is an Instance of a factory, it is a return from a factory so it isn't technically a module that I can include

Comment: Could you please show the StartController code as well?  That would make answering your question much easier.

Comment: @Grant it sounds like that's your problem then. Angular can't know where to get `userInstance` unless it's registered as a provider.
Inject the factory instead and use it in your controller to get or create the userInstance.

Whatever you inject into StartController is found by reflection. That means angular will run `toString()` on the controller function to find the arguments, then it will look for each provider from the list of all providers that have been registered like this: `myModule.factory('MyFactoryName', function(){ ... });'` < You likely have not registered `userInstance`.

Comment: @HankScorpio So how would I make a userInstance into a provider? Or would I literally just include the factory that creates it and then use that factory to create an instances of it in a beforeEach block, then include that into the test?

Comment: I wouldn't do it like that, but if you do then you can use one of the $provide methods here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide
`constant()` or `value()` probably.
I prefer to use a service to return the userInstance using a `getInstance()` method (google: singleton/multiton pattern). That way your userInstance can be created when needed.
The reason I wouldn't do it with a provider is it would make the controller dependant on another module having already created that userInstance before the controller is instantiated. Using a service allows for a more independent controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$controller` is a call to `$inject` but treated as a service. What happens is you are instantiating the controller but because `$inject` is  used, and you are not passing `userInstance`, it looks for a provider which isn't found. You need to make sure to pass the service/factory/resolve to your `$controller` method. By mocking it out and passing it to the controller, you can isolate what you expect to happen and only test the controller in this unit test.

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    userInstanceMock = {
        // mock out all methods here
        foo: sinon.stub()
    }
    ctrl = $controller('StartController', {
        $scope: scope,
        userInstace: userInstaceMock
    });
}));
```